# Javascript - Toggle Element only works one way! Also help required for URL append

Tags: javascript, ajax, append, toggle, element

I am trying to use a toggle script to show and hide certain elements of a page... it works fine hiding the Table containing a list of links and showing the Table with the content inside, but using it to reverse this does not work at all!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getElement(iElementId)
{
if (document.all) 
{
    return document.all[iElementId];
}
if (document.getElementById)
{
    return document.getElementById(iElementId);
}
}

function toggleElement(oElement)
{
if (oElement.style.display == "none")
{
    oElement.style.display = "inline";
}
else if (oElement.style.display == "inline")
{
    oElement.style.display = "none";
}
else
{
    oElement.style.display = "none";
}
}
function OpenPage(name) {
    // other function not relevant here //
toggleElement( getElement('MainTable'));
toggleElement( getElement('ContentTable'));
return false;
}
function Switchback(){
//  document.getElementById(MainTable).style.display = "inline";
//    document.getElementById('ContentTable').style.display = "none";
toggleElement( getElement('MainTable'));
toggleElement( getElement('ContentTable'));
return false;
}
</script>
```

Even just trying a "getElementByID" function doesn't work for the switching back to displaying the main table of links and hiding the content table... Any way to make it work? thanks.

(also, whilst we're at it, what is the best way to append a URL using Javascript/AJAX? as the page is presently forum/index.php but when a link to a forum is clicked I want the URL to append to forum/index.php?f= and then the relevant number)

Comment: Worked fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/megsuma/ZYEGs/ - what browser are you testing in?

Comment: Yeah appears to work fine, thanks phatskat for making the JSFiddle, can only assume you have a fault somewhere else perhaps in the // other function not relevent here //.  Please make a JSFiddle that shows your problem.

Comment: Oddly enough it seems to be working!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getElement(iElementId)
{
if (document.all) 
{
    return document.all[iElementId];
}
if (document.getElementById)
{
    return document.getElementById(iElementId);
}
}

function toggleElement(oElement)
{
if (oElement.style.display == "none")
{
    oElement.style.display = "inline";
}
else if (oElement.style.display == "inline")
{
    oElement.style.display = "none";
}
else
{
    oElement.style.display = "none";
}
}
function OpenPage(name) {
    // other function not relevant here //
toggleElement( getElement('MainTable'));
toggleElement( getElement('ContentTable'));
return false;
}
function Switchback(){
//  document.getElementById(MainTable).style.display = "inline";
//    document.getElementById('ContentTable').style.display = "none";
toggleElement( getElement('MainTable'));
toggleElement( getElement('ContentTable'));
return false;
}
</script>
```